# Stronger boosting by date in Solr

Tags: search, solr, solr4

Boosting by date field in solr is defined as:

```
{!boost b=recip(ms(NOW,datefield),3.16e-11,1,1)}
```

I looked everywhere (examples: [Solr Dismax Config for Boost Scoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175938/solr-dismax-config-for-boost-scoring?rq=1) and [Solr boost for multivalued date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152902/solr-boost-for-multivalued-date-field) and they all reference the [SolrRelevancyFAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents)), same definition that is used. But I found that this is not boosting my results sufficiently. How can I make this date boosting stronger?

User is searching for two keywords. Both items contain both keywords (in same order) in both title and description. Neither of the keywords is repeated.

And the solr debug output is waaay too confusing to me to understand the problem.

Now, this is not a huge problem. 99% of queries work fine and produce expected results, so its not like solr is not working at all, I just found this situation that is very confusing to me and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: So basically you want to know how the boosting you are using works, to understand which of the values you need to change, in order to make current (closer to NOW) documents more relevant?

Comment: Yes, which values and how (positive/negative, large or small)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> User is searching for two keywords. Both items contain both keywords
>   (in same order) in both title and description. Neither of the keywords
>   is repeated.

Well, by your example, it is clear that your results have landed into a `tie` situation. To understand this problem of **confusing** debug output and devise a **tie-breaker** policy, it is important to understand [`dismax`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser).

With `DisMax` queries, the different terms of the user input are executed against different fields, if many of them hit (the term appears in different fields in the same `document`) the hit that scores higher is used, but what happens with the other sub-queries that hit in that `document` for the term? Well, that’s what the `tie` parameter defines. `DisMax` will calculate the score for a term query as:

```
score= [score of the top scoring subquery] + tie * (sum of other hitting subqueries)
```

In consequence, the `tie` parameter is a value between 0 and 1 that will define if the `Dismax` will only consider the max hit `score` for a term (setting `tie`=0), all the hits for a term (setting `tie`=1) or something between those two extremes.

The `boost` parameter is very similar to the `bf` parameter, but instead of adding its result to the final score, it will multiply it. This is only available in the **Extended Dismax Query Parser** or the **Lucid Query Parser**.

There is an interesting article [Comparing Boost Methods](http://nolanlawson.com/2012/06/02/comparing-boost-methods-in-solr/) of SOLR which may be useful to you.

References for this answer:

- [Advanced Apache Solr boosting: a case study](http://www.triquanta.nl/blog/advanced-apache-solr-boosting-case-study)
- [Using Solr’s Dismax Tie Parameter](http://tm.durusau.net/?p=21573)

Shishir

Comment: This looks like a likely problem, now I'll just need to try and find a way to implement this in PHP.Thanks.

Answer (score 48):

**recip(x, m, a, b)** implements `f(x) = a/(xm+b)` with :

- `x` : the document age in ms, defined as `ms(NOW,<datefield>)`.
- `m` : a constant that defines a time scale which is used to apply boost. It should be relative to what you consider an old document age (a *reference_time*) in milliseconds. For example, choosing a *reference_time* of 1 year (3.16e10ms) implies to use its inverse : `3.16e-11` (1/3.16e10 rounded).
- `a` and `b` are constants (defined arbitrarily).
- `xm = 1` when the document is 1 *reference_time* old (multiplier = `a/(1+b)`).
  `xm ≈ 0` when the document is new, resulting in a value close to `a/b`.
- Using the same value for a and b ensures the multiplier doesn't exceed 1 with recent documents.
- With `a = b = 1`, a 1 *reference_time* old document has a multiplier of about 1/2, a 2 *reference_time* old document has a multiplier of about 1/3, and so on.

**How to make a date boosting stronger ?**

- Increase `m` : choose a lower *reference_time* for example 6 months, that gives us `m = 6.33e-11`. Comparing to a 1 year reference, the multiplier decreases 2x faster as the document age increases.
- Decreasing `a` and `b` expands the response curve of the function. This can be very agressive, see [this example](http://www.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/potter-timothy-boosting-documents-in-solr) (page 8).
- Apply a boost to the boost function itself with the [`bf` (Boost Functions)](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thebf_BoostFunctions_Parameter) parameter (this is a dismax parameter so it requires using DisMax or eDisMax query parser), eg. :

  ```
  bf=recip(ms(NOW,datefield),3.16e-11,1,1)^2.0
  ```

---

It is important to note a few things :

- `bf` is an **additive** boost and acts as a *bonus* added to the score of newer documents.
- `{!boost b}` is a **multiplicative** boost and acts more as a *penalty* applied to the score of older document.
- A bf score (the "bonus" added to the global score) is calculated independently of the relevancy score (the global score), meaning that a resultset with higher scores may not be impacted as much as a resultset with lower scores. In contrast, multiplicative boosts affect scores the same way regardless of the resultset relevancy, that's why it is usually preferred.
- Do not use `recip()` for dates more than one *reference_time* in the future or it will yield negative values.

See also this very insightful post by Nolan Lawson on [Comparing boost methods in Solr](https://nolanlawson.com/2012/06/02/comparing-boost-methods-in-solr/).

Comment: Yes, this is an very thorough explanation. I wish this was the accepted answer.

Comment: Great explanation, very useful. Small typo near xm = 1: multiplier needs parenthesis, ie a/(1+b)

Comment: ...However, I can't get the math to match: Your example with 6 months seems off - wouldn't it be something like m = 1/(0.5*3.16e10) = 6.33e-11?

Comment: @corolla You're right, when using 6 months as reference m=6.3e-11 rounded, I don't know where I got the 'e-8' from.. thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

There is an example very well presented in the [ReciprocalFloatFunction](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/function/valuesource/ReciprocalFloatFunction.html?is-external=true) that will give you a clear view on how the boosting recipe works. If you find that `dismax` does not offer you enough control over the boosting, you will have to do some tinkering with `BoostQParserPlugin`.

> A multiplier of 3.16e-11 changes the units from milliseconds to years
>   (since there are about 3.16e10 milliseconds per year). Thus, a very
>   recent date will yield a value close to 1/(0+1) or 1, a date a year in
>   the past will get a multiplier of about 1/(1+1) or 1/2, and date two
>   years old will yield 1/(2+1) or 1/3.

Comment: What do you mean by "have to do some tinkering"?

Comment: This one is a bit out of date but is still relevant http://nolanlawson.com/2012/06/02/comparing-boost-methods-in-solr. It will give you are comparison of all available boost methods. What I meant by tinkering is that you would implement/extend the BoostQParserPlugin to produce yourself a BoostedQuery or build a custom Request handler to achieve the same. This may be an overstretch for your scenario, take a look at multiplicative boost with edismax. http://www.typo3-media.com/blog/solr-recip-boosting.html - here you can test your recip function.