# Solr: Boost by string field

Tags: solr, solr-boost

How can I boost a query by a string field?
I've found only resources explaining [date boosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017616/stronger-boosting-by-date-in-solr).

E.g. these documents should be boosted in this order:

1. priority=a
2. priority=b
3. priority=c

I know, that I could sort by priority, but I want to combine this field with the solr relevancy mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is a boost function using rord()

```
bf=rord(priority)^10
```

rord maps a string to an integer, which can then be used for boosting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply custom weights to each value; i.e. say that `b` is two times more important than `a`, or that your priorities aren't necessarily ordered (i.e. `c` should be boosted more than `b`, but not more than `a`), you can add a boost query with each weight:

```
bq=priority:a^10 priority:b^2 priority:c^5
```