# Explain Apache SOLR boost function

Tags: boost, solr-boost

I'm try to implement a logic in APACHE SOLR so that documents older than 2 years should get penalty based on the difference in number of days or months.

I am using this boost function, which I got after googling a lot.

```
 recip(ms(NOW,publicationDate),3.16e-11,1,1) // Currently it is set to use 1 year
```

Can any please confirm if this penalties old documents or what ?

Thanks

Comment: did you try it yourself?

Comment: yes I did try, but not sure what it actually does. ?

Comment: The short answer is yes, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017616/stronger-boosting-by-date-in-solr/22213417#22213417) to see how the penalty is applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A reciprocal function with `recip(x,m,a,b)` implementing `a/(m*x+b)`.
>   m,a,b are constants, x is any numeric field or arbitrarily complex
>   function.

[image]

In case of your parameters, your function will look like this:

```
f(x) = 1 /(3.16e-11*x + 1)
```

> Function `ms` returns milliseconds of difference between it's
>   arguments.
>
> Dates are relative to the Unix or POSIX time epoch, midnight, January
>   1, 1970 UTC.

Imagine, your publication date is September 1st 2015, ms will get us NOW = 1507725936061 and publication date is 1441065600000 and the whole result will be around 0.3 which will be the score for this document.

For publication date of yesterday, we will get score of 0.99, which leads to the idea, so, this formula will apply penalty to every document not only to ones which are 2 years old. For example, for the same day 1 year ago the score will be 0.5

I could think potentially about sorting by this function (starting from Solr 6)

```
if(gt(ms(mydatefield,NOW-2YEARS),0),1,recip(ms(NOW,publicationDate),3.16e-11,1,1))
```

I didn't test it (not sure about NOW-2YEARS part), but basically, i'm doing this:

```
if mydatefield - NOW-2YEARS greater 
    than 0 => score will be 1.0 
    else   => I'm calculating reciprocal function
```

One last remark: there are `3.16e10` milliseconds in a year, so one can scale dates to fractions of a year with the inverse, or `3.16e-11`, so for 2 years, you may select something different.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Can I tune ti so that it only applies penalty to documents which are two years old.

Comment: Hi,can you please also tell the value that I should use for 2 years.
instead of 3.16e-11

Thanks

Comment: 3.16e-11 should be fine

Comment: by the way, what exactly reciprocal does in simple terms, does it boost documents or penalties ?

Comment: in simple terms it usually penalites, take a look at the graph, i've posted. function is decreasing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156476/discussion-between-farhan-tahir-and-mysterion).

Comment: I'm using this formula
if(gt(ms(created_at,NOW-2YEARS),0),3,recip(ms(NOW,created_at),3.16e-11,1,1))

But I have to use 3 instead of 1, as using 1 was returning documents of 2013 and 2014 as well. which I don't want.

What you think why it showed those documents. ?